# Отсортировать массив структур по выбранному полю структуры.

Tags: c++11, c++

Здравствуйте, есть такая структура:

```
struct Book {
std::string GenreCode;
std::string Author;
std::string BookName;
unsigned short PublicationYear;
unsigned int NumbersOfCopies;

bool operator==(const Book& struc) {
        return (GenreCode == struc.GenreCode && Author == struc.Author && BookName ==
        struc.BookName&& PublicationYear == struc.PublicationYear);
    }
};
```

Также есть массив структур:

```
std::vector<Book> bookCollection;
```

Мне нужно отсортировать этот массив по выбранному пользователем элементу структуры, например, по

```
book.Author;
//или
book.BookName;
```

Конечно, можно написать 4 метода для сортировки (первые 4 элемента структуры), но хочется сделать это как-нибудь поэлегантнее. Можете подсказать как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно.

Используйте [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) и лямбды.

Например, сортировка по автору:

```
std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), [](const Book& a, const Book& b) {
    return a.Author < b.Author;
});
```

Полный рабочий пример [здесь](https://ideone.com/YOKoH5).

Comment: Спасибо большое, лямбд пока не знаю. Вот подвернулся способ подучить :)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Без лямбд вам бы пришлось создавать 4 предопределённые сравнивающие функции. А так вы в различных участках кода можете задать самые разные условия сортировки, хоть по длине фамилии минус номер месяца рождения.

Comment: Кстати, в Си (по крайней мере в gcc, но не в g++) теперь тоже есть похожая штука - внутренние функции (не помню, как точно называется)

      int cmpa(const void *a1, const void *a2) {
        return strcmp(((struct Book *)a1)->author, ((struct Book *)a2)->author);
      }
      qsort(books, n, sizeof(books[0]), cmpa);
 
Чуть длиннее, чем в C++.

Comment: Лямбды хороши тем, что "помнят" контекст:

    int maxlen = 5;
    std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), [maxlen](const Book& a, const Book& b) {
        return a.Author.substring(maxlen) < b.Author.substring(maxlen);
    });

Comment: @VladD, а лямбды нелокальный (т.е. переменные в вызывающей функции) контекст видят?

Видимо нет, поэтому-то и придуман специальный синтаксис, что именно из нелокальных переменных видит лямбда.

Тогда такой вопрос, лямбда видит их (контекстные переменные) по адресу или по значению в момент вызова?

Что будет с лямбдой в случае косвенной рекурсии (функция в контексте)? (Подозреваю, что ничего страшного, каждая активация в новом фрейме стека).

Comment: Лямбды видят только контекст в точке их объявления, контекст _вызывающей_ функции им не доступен. Им видны и изменения переменных, если попросить об этом (`[&maxlen]` вместо `[maxlen]`): <https://ideone.com/Sy9H5u>. Если переменная, "захваченная" лямбдой по ссылке, умрёт, возникнет undefined behaviour. (В отличие от C#, где лямбды "удлиняют жизнь" захваченным переменным.)

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, теперь понятно, кратко и понятно что происходит.

Осталось 2 вопросика.

Несколько переменных в контексте разделяют запятыми?

Функцию (не результат вызова, а указатель на нее) передавать можно?

Comment: @avp: несколько переменных разделяют и правда запятыми, для каждой можно отдельно указать, захватывается по значению или по ссылке. Можно захватить _все_ локальные переменные таким образом: `[=, &maxlen]` (все по значению, но `maxlen` по ссылке). Ещё отдельно надо захватывать `this` (только по значению). Видимые в точке объявления функции доступны без явного захвата, методы классов — если захвачен `this`.

---
Тип лямбда-функции implementation-dependent, но можно использовать `auto` или присвоить её переменной типа `std::function` (бывший `boost::function`).

Comment: @avp: а внутренние функции классная вещь, не знал о них раньше.

Comment: @VladD, да я сам не так давно (кстати, здесь на ХК) о них узнал.

Жаль, что в С++ нет их, а в Си лямбд.

Comment: @avp, @VladD Добавлю еще пять копеек: если лямбда не использует контекст, то она может быть приведена к типу "указатель на функцию" с сигнатурой, совпадающей с сигнатурой лямбды.

Comment: Ну и в стандарте C++14 нас ожидают полиморфные лямбды -- вместо типа аргумента у них можно использовать auto.

Answer (score 4):

Наваял следующее решение. Поля все равно надо перечислять явно, зато компараторы выводятся автоматически:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename Field>
std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> comparator(Field T::* field) {
    return [field](const T& b1, const T& b2) {
        return b1.*field < b2.*field;
    };
}

typedef std::function<bool(const Book&, const Book&)> BooksComparator;

void sortBy(const std::string& field_name, std::vector<Book>* bookCollection) {
   static const std::map<std::string, BooksComparator> comparators{
       {"GenreCode", comparator(&Book::GenreCode)},
       {"Author", comparator(&Book::Author)},
       {"BookName", comparator(&Book::BookName)},
       {"PublicationYear", comparator(&Book::PublicationYear)}
   };
   auto it = comparators.find(field_name);
   if (it == comparators.end()) {
     throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid value for 'field_name'.");
   }
   std::sort(bookCollection->begin(), bookCollection->end(), it->second);
}
```

Использовать очень просто:

```
sortBy("GenreCode", &bookCollection);
sortBy("PublicationYear", &bookCollection);
```

Comment: Круто! Хотя ошибка в имени поля будет выявлена лишь в рантайме :-)

Comment: @dzhioev, спасибо, буду разбираться